# 04 vw beetle starting problem

Tags: vw, fuel-system, beetle

This used to happen when the car was warm but now it happens all the time.

*When I go to start the car it just keeps turning over and does not start but I take the key out and try again and sometimes it fires right up no problem.*

I've tried to cycle the key on and off a few times and try to listen for the fuel pump turning on but can't really hear it and when it does fire up I don't believe I hear the fuel pump.  It had a cat converter code that popped up could that have anything to do with it? (don't think so, I cleared it anyway)

It did say the intake air temp was 80 and outside it was around 60 (normal?).
I've tried to give it gas while starting it (don't think the computer will let it start with the pedal down?) I did this once and once it started and got it up to 3k rpm without any hesitation.
Today I was gonna go spend $20 on a fuel tester gauge to see if it has pressure in the fuel rail.

edit: after it sits for a while it tends to start up just fine.

Could it be a bad sensor telling the computer to inject too much fuel or not enough to start the engine? How can I test that?

Any ideas on what else it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested for fuel pressure and it had 0 psi!
Tested fuse and connections, also tested the fuel pump connection pins and it had 0 volts.
Found the relay (it's under the dash above the pedals, need to unscrew about 3-4 T20 screws), **I pushed the relay with my hand and the fuel pump ticked on and built fuel pressure!
I replaced the relay and it seems to be working just fine!**
Hopefully, that was the fix, a bad relay.

I did think it was the connection pins that the relay plugs into but it seems to be working fine, time will tell if its the pins or just a new relay (bumps/pushing relay out..etc. time will tell)